# Dynamic connection string in DAAB

Tags: c#, .net, daab

I am having a situation where i need multiple connection strings to process a request, but i am not able to implement this using the Microsoft enterprise library.

somebody please tell me how can i set the connection string dynamically.

found similar questions on internet, but none solving my problem, hence posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Its not possible to set the connection string dynamically, however you can write a Custom database factory to create a database with dynamic connection string

```
    public static class CustomDatabaseFactory
    {
        static readonly DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

        public static Database CreateDatabase(string connectionString)
        {
            return new GenericDatabase(connectionString, dbProviderFactory);
        }
    }
```

and instead of calling this

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

call this method

```
Database db = CustomDatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(connstring);
```

worked well for me!

Comment: oh...yes, Thats what i was looking for. Bulls-eye :) thanks a lot SKR. works like a charm